# Displaying a DICOM dataset as 3D representation

Tags: ami.js

I am trying to show a DICOM Series as a 3D representation. It worked with a different set of data but with the current one, the 3D image does not show up. The output values in the datastack of windowCenter and windowWidth are -964 and -664. I am using the latest version of AMI.js but still cannot display the DICOMs as 3D.

Do I have to convert the negativ values somehow, so that they turn out as positive values? Or do you have any other idea why I cannot display the Data?

I am loading the Data with the AMI.VolumeLoader, here is the important bit of code:

```
let loader = new AMI.VolumeLoader();
  loader.load(files)
    .then(() => {
        let series = loader.data[0].mergeSeries(loader.data)[0];
        loader.free();
        loader = null;
        let stack = series.stack[0];

        //stack Helper
        vrHelper = new AMI.VolumeRenderingHelper(stack);
        scene.add(vrHelper);
        //LUT
        lut = new AMI.LutHelper('lut-canvases');
        lut.luts = AMI.LutHelper.presetLuts();
        lut.lutsO = AMI.LutHelper.presetLutsO();
        //update related uniforms
        vrHelper.uniforms.uTextureLUT.value = lut.texture;
        vrHelper.uniforms.uLut.value = 1;

        // camera
        let centerLPS = stack.worldCenter();
        camera.lookAt(centerLPS.x, centerLPS.y, centerLPS.z);
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        controls.target.set(centerLPS.x, centerLPS.y, centerLPS.z);
    })
    .catch((error) => window.console.log(error));
```

A different set of Data is showing as it should be: 
[image: Dicom series as 3D representation]

The other set of data is just not showing up and I don't even get an error message. 
[image]

Comment: How did you get the latest version of ami.js?

Comment: I cloned the git repository, installed it with "yarn install" and then used the library with "yarn build:ami". The console output of my application is stating "AMI 0.0.23-dev" as version of AMI. @Nicolas is that the wrong version?

Comment: that should be the good one - can you update the source code and rebuild to make sure you are running the latest version?
Can you share some code or put a demo online?

Comment: What do you mean "I can not display the data"? Can you be more specific? Code and screenshots and anonymized test data can help.

Comment: I have added some code and screenshots, but I can't share the DICOM Data. I can give some values of the DICOM Tags, if you might want them @Nicolas?

Comment: Does it work if you do not show the slices?

Comment: No it dosn't, then there is just an empty screen.

Comment: you did clone it recently right? Have a look at the window level from the stack, at the offset and and window level from the stack helper and also the window level you are trying to display.

Comment: also how to you change the window/level from the vr helper? you need to use the windowCenter and windowWidth setters.

Comment: Thank you for help, it is working now! My fault was, that I had build the newest dev version of ami.js and embedded it in my project but, somehow the project still used the old version, even though it showed 
in the console, that it is using the dev version.